# How to debug already installed Python application?

Tags: python, python-2.7, debugging

I am trying to debug an [application](https://github.com/cuckoosandbox/cuckoo) that is written in Python 2. Problem is, before application can be run, it must be installed (according to the documentation) like this:

```
python setup.py develop
```

Application (Cuckoo Sandbox) then can be run like this:

```
cuckoo -d
```

> With the new Python package developing and testing code now works slightly different than it used to be. As one
>   will first have to Install Cuckoo before being able to use it in the first place, a simple modify-and-test development
>   sequence doesn’t work out-of-the-box as it used to do.

Is it possible to somehow debug such application?

Later in the (unfinished) docs there is a mention of debugging web interface which I am not sure would get me to the code I need to debug and it also requires PyCharm Professional. I am using PyCharm Community but I am willing to use any other free IDE or debugger.

Answer (score 0):

It will be difficult to debug if you are working only with compiled .pyo and .pyc files, which is all that you might have from an installed application. It is possible that the install includes some source files. You will have to figure out where it is installed, which is platform specific. Since many projects (including cuckoo) are open source, I would recommend cloning the [Github repository](https://github.com/cuckoosandbox/cuckoo) and debugging from that.